# AlertDialog doesn't display items from ListAdapter Hide options

Tags: android

When I try to set the Alert using ArrayAdaptor to display a set of 
items, the list is displayed but the items' characters are invisible. 
If the item is selected, then the characters are visible.  Scratching 
my head on why.  Appreciate any advice.  Below is the code and the 
screenshot from the emulator.

```
public class MessageTest extends Activity implements 
View.OnClickListener { 
        public final static String debugTag = "MessageDemo::"; 
        Button alert; 
        Button toast; 
        String[] items={"item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5" }; 


        @Override 
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { 
                super.onCreate(icicle); 


                setContentView(R.layout.message); 


                alert=(Button)findViewById(R.id.alert); 
                alert.setOnClickListener(this); 
        } 


        public void onClick(View view) { 
                if (view==alert) { 
                        ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, items); 


                        new AlertDialog.Builder(this) 
                                .setTitle("MessageTest") 
                                .setSingleChoiceItems(aa, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
{ 
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int which) { 
                                             Log.d(MessageDemo.debugTag, 
"DialogInterface.OnClickListener::onClick() is called -> which = 
"+which); 
                                        } 
                                }) 
                                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert) 
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) { 
                                             Log.d(MessageDemo.debugTag, "OK button is clicked -> sumthin 
= "+sumthin); 
                                        } 
                                }) 
                                .setNeutralButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) { 
                                             Log.d(MessageDemo.debugTag, "Close button is clicked -> 
sumthin = "+sumthin); 
                                                // do nothing -- it will close on its own 
                                        } 
                                }) 
                                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
{ 
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) { 
                                             Log.d(MessageDemo.debugTag, "Cancel button is clicked -> 
sumthin = "+sumthin); 
                                        } 
                                }) 
                                .show(); 
                } 
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure but AlertDialog background is grey and the characters of the ArrayAdapter too, so grey on grey you can't see them maybe !

Answer (score 9):

I know I'm a bit late at answering, but I had the same problem and I fixed it by simply changing

```
ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, items);
```

to

```
ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, items);
```

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

As Quintin already mentioned in the comment, the problems reason maybe that the text color and background of the list items are the same. Use another view template for your list items, eg. `android.R.layout.select_dialog_item`:

```
builder.setAdapter(
    new ArrayAdapter<Object>(context, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, my_array)
    {
         @Override
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
         {                         
             View row;                         
             if (null == convertView) 
             {
                 row = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, null);
             } 
             else 
             {
                 row = convertView;
             }                          
             TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
             tv.setText(getItem(position).toString());

             return row;                                          
         }

    }, ...
```

The layout inflater can be grabbed over a context:

```
final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```